# Handling 0x19 in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have encountered a problem when input xml contains the character 0x19. I have created a demo xslt to reproduce the issue.
My demo xslt looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="param1"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <Value>
          <xsl:value-of select="$param1"/>
      </Value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I am passing the character 0x19 as `param1`. The below output gets generated.

```
<Value>&#x19;</Value>
```

which is an invalid xml. How can I get it right?

Comment: If the input stream contains character 0x19, then the input is not XML.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that

```
 <Value>&#x19;</Value>
```

is not well-formed XML 1.0 - XML 1.0 does not allow any control characters below U+0020 except U+0009 (tab), U+000A (LF) and U+000D (CR), not even when expressed as numeric character references, so it is simply not possible to include that character in an XML 1.0 document.  The processor is wrong to produce that output, it *should* raise an error to complain that you've tried to insert an illegal character in the output.

However it *is* well formed XML 1.1, which allows control characters as `&#` references but not as literals.  If your processor supports this (and the donwnstream components that will be receiving your output support it too) then it may be sufficient to add `version="1.1"` to the `xsl:output` instruction

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.1"/>
```

to tell it to output XML 1.1 instead of XML 1.0.